# Adding more than one document in alfresco datalist association using javascript

Tags: javascript, alfresco

I am new to alfresco. I have a custom model that handles employee records using datalist. If the record to be added is new, i can read the file name scanned and attach the related metadat and the file in an association  using javascript. The file scannned from the scanner has the following infomation 21420-victor mathew-HR-copy of id-10.pdf.

The first value represents the staff unique id. my problem is that when the second document is scanned, i want it added in the datalist as an attachment, but my script is creating a new record. this is my javascript:

var docname       = document.properties["cm:name"]; // get the name of the file
    splitFile         = docname.split("-"); // split to get metadata

```
fileCustomerNo    = splitFile[0];   
fileCustomerName  = splitFile[1];
fileDept          = splitFile[2]; 
fileDocType       = splitFile[5];   


    var testList = companyhome.childByNamePath("Sites/Employee/dataLists/823bd590-cbb7-4ea2-b9af-964ab4f1023a"); 
    var testEntry = testList.createNode(null, "tq:employee");


        var query= "@tq\\:fileCustomerNo:" + fileCustomerNo;                        
        var results = search.luceneSearch(query);           
        if(results !=null && results.length !=0)
        {

                var relatedarticles = companyhome.createNode("paymentDocs", "cm:content");
                relatedarticles.properties.content.write(document.properties.content);                  
                testEntry.createAssociation(relatedarticles, "tq:related" );                    
                relatedarticles.save();
        }else{


    testEntry.properties["tq:CustomerNo"] = fileCustomerNo; 
    testEntry.properties["tq:CustomerName"] = fileCustomerName; 
    testEntry.properties["tq:dept"] = fileDept;         
    testEntry.save();               

    var relatedarticle = companyhome.createNode("paymentDocs", "cm:content");       
    relatedarticle.properties["cm:name"] = docname;
    relatedarticle.properties.content.write(document.properties.content);       
    testEntry.createAssociation(relatedarticle, "tq:related");
    relatedarticle.save();
    }
```

Someone help me on how to add a new document to an existing association just like the way i can click edit and browse within alfresco and add the document.

Answer (score 0):

If the multiplicity on the association as defined in the content model is set to allow multiple target objects on the association, then you simply create the additional association. For example, here is a snippet from a content model which would allow multiple documents to be associated because "many" is set to true:

```
<target>
    <class>sys:base</class>
    <mandatory>false</mandatory>
    <many>true</many>
</target>
```

If "many" were set to false, you would receive an error when you tried to create the additional association.